# Azure Devops build pipeline is getting failed on steps such as Build Solution

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a self host agent on my local machine.

I am getting error as below

> [error]No agent found in pool Test which satisfies the following demand:
>    visualstudio. All demands: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.115.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pipeline has demands that don't meet the capabilities of any of your agents, your pipeline won't start. 
From the error message, the tasks in your build definition require msbuild and visualstudio available on the build agent in order to queue a build, please install Visual Studio on your build agent, then restart the build agent. Restarting the build agent will capture the added capabilities.

Comment: How to install visual studio on my self hosted agent ?

Comment: you can check it from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I got installed with visual studio on my machine. Now i am running the build pipeline with self hosted agent. Its fialing at the step NuGet Restore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Visual Studio on your Self Hosted Agent, then you can simply download & install Visual Studio Community Edition which is free for one developer.

This can be used for Self Hosted Agent.